# Error on Latitude and Longitude - Google Maps API JS 3.0

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

After a while, Google Maps seems to change the property name (Qa or Pa) to Na or another name.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    AlertPos(event.latLng);
  });
}

function AlertPos (location) {

    // try to show the latitude and longitude
    document.getElementById('lat').value = location.Qa; 
    document.getElementById('long').value = location.Pa; 
    alert(location.Qa)
    alert(location.Pa)
}
```

This affects my application. Can any body help?

Answer (score 10):

Use `lat()` and `lng()`:

```
function AlertPos (location) {        
    // try to show the latitude and longitude
    document.getElementById('lat').value = location.lat(); 
    document.getElementById('long').value = location.lng(); 
    alert(location.lat()); 
    alert(location.lng());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Work ;)

Comment: Awesome, couldn't find this in the documentation!

Comment: Was just stumped by this. My map application spontaneously stopped working, since I, like fmlvaz, was relying on the `Qa` and `Pa` values (although they were `Qa` and `Ra` earlier!)

Comment: I was relying on Na and Oa, then they changed it to Ra and Sa... wtf google... but thanks for the lat() lng() functions... didnt notice them :)