# Google maps places Lattitude and Longitude object keeps changing?

Tags: google-maps

I'm fetching a bunch of markers with the Places API. The attributes keep changing, can someone explain me why ?

I use something like (given __place is the result of a Places API call)

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(__place.geometry.location.Qa, 
  __place.geometry.location.Ra);
```

It used to be `__place.geometry.location.Ia`, `__place.geometry.location.Ja` then
`__place.geometry.location.Oa` / `Pa`
and now 
`__place.geometry.location.Qa` / `Ra`

Why is it always changing, is it supposed to be like that or what ? I don't understand how one can develop something with places API if it keeps changing ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are internal structures, you should never use them.

Use functions .lat() (instead of Qa) and .lng() (instead of Ra) for coordinates.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

for example:

latitude of the map center `var lat = map.getCenter().lat();`

longitude of the map center `var lng = map.getCenter().lng();`

And read this [Error on Latitude and Longitude - Google Maps API JS 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273572/error-on-latitude-and-longitude-google-maps-api-js-3-0)

Comment: Ok but this isn't related to markers.. __place is the result of using the function new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map); which returns an array of places. If i can't use these variables, what should i use in place.geometry.location ?

Comment: OK got it, i replaced iA by .lat() and it works, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It should be __place.geometry.location.lat() and __place.geometry.location.lng().

Can you provide a link to where you are seeing this?